# Was ist "gutem Grund" für eine Deklinationsform?

Tags: declension

Für eine Software brauche ich eine vollständige Liste der möglichen Deklinationsformen eines Begriffs, zum Beispiel "guter Grund". Es gibt die offensichtlichen bestimmten und unbestimmten Fälle:

- der gute Grund
- des guten Grundes
- dem guten Grund
- den guten Grund
- die guten Gründe
- der guten Gründe
- den guten Gründen
- die guten Gründe
- ein guter Grund
- eines guten Grundes
- einem guten Grund
- einen guten Grund
- (viele) gute Gründe
- (vieler) guter Gründe
- (vielen) guten Gründen
- (viele) gute Gründe

So weit so gut. Allerdings gibt es darüber hinaus wenigstens noch die Form "gutem Grund", zum Beispiel in "Ich schweige aus gutem Grund."

- Wie heißt diese Form? Ist es einfach ein Sonderfall des unbestimmten Dativ Singular?
- Gibt es weitere solche Sonderfälle? Oder ist die obige Liste von 17 Formen vollständig?

Comment: Wenn es um *gut* plus *Grund* geht, warum werden dann *(dem/einem) guten Grund* separat gezählt?

Comment: @DavidVogt Für einen gegebenen grammatischen Zusammenhang (Kasus, Numerus, Art des vorangestellten Artikels) soll die richtige Form Identifiziert werden. Auch wenn zwei Formen identisch sind, sind sie in dieser Klassifizierung unterschiedliche Fälle.

Comment: Die Art des Artikels spielt für die Form des Adjektivs aber nicht unmittelbar eine Rolle: *dem/einem/jedem/keinem/diesem/manchem/… guten Grund*. (Und dann gibt es neben *gutem* noch *guter, guten Grund* ohne Artikel.)

Answer (score 5):

Canoonet.eu bietet Deklinationstabellen für Adjektive und Substantive an.

[Hier](http://www.canoonet.eu/inflection/gut:A) ist zum Beispiel die Tabelle für *gut*.
 "*aus gutem Grund*" ist Dativ, maskulin, Singular der sogenannten "[starken Flexion](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexion#Deklination_bei_Adjektiven)". Diese wird bei fehlendem oder flexionslosem Artikelwort benutzt.

Mit diesem Beispiel hast Du selbst schon gezeigt, dass Deine List noch nicht vollständig ist, die starke Flexion fehlt.

Weiterhin schreibst Du nichts darüber, ob Du die Steigerungsformen der Adjektive berücksichtigen willst: Sollen nur *gute Gründe* Eingang in Deine Software finden, oder auch *bessere Gründe* und *die besten Gründe*?

Comment: Von diesen Flexionssorten habe ich tatsächlich noch nie etwas gehört. Dann werde ich wohl neben bestimmten und unbestimmten Artikeln eine weitere Kategorie einbauen müssen.. In meiner Software geht es nur darum, in Sätzen die richtige Form von vorgegebenen Begriffen einfügen zu lassen; Steigerung ist also für mich also nicht nötig.

Answer (score 2):

Da hast du dir "etwas Schönes" vorgenommen, denn wie sich bis jetzt herausstellt, geht es nicht nur um "*gut + Grund*" sondern um "*ARTIKEL + gut + Grund*", also um die komplette Nominalphrase. Als ich mich selbst einmal mit einer ähnlichen Fragestellung beschäftigt hatte, waren mir ein paar Dinge aufgefallen, auf die ich hier kurz aufmerksam machen will.

Die Frage, was alles zu den Artikeln bzw. Artikelwörtern zu zählen ist, ist nicht ohne weiteres entscheidbar. Innerhalb der Nominalgruppe entscheidet jedoch der Artikel mit darüber, wie das Adjektiv zu flektieren ist. Das geht ja aus deiner Aufzählung bereits hervor. Soll dann "*gut + Grund*" mit allen denkbaren Artikelwörtern aufgezählt werden?

Eine weitere Frage ist, ob alle Kombinationen, die man bilden kann, auch überhaupt vorkommen können. Während man

> das ist kalt**er** Kaffee

ohne weiteres sagen kann, ist

> *das ist gut**er** Grund

nicht möglich, weil *Grund*, anders als *Kaffee*, nicht ohne weiteres unter der Perspektive der Nicht-Gezähltheit benutzt werden kann. Die Grammatiken nennen das überwiegend "Zählbarkeit" und stellen es als eine mehr oder weniger stabile Eigenschaft des Nomens dar, aber eine solche Sichtweise ist stark vereinfachend.  Wie ist es zum Beispiel mit

> er hat gut**en** Grund, anzunehmen, dass sein Leben in Gefahr ist.

"Zählbar" oder "nicht zählbar"? Im Plural kann die "Zählbarkeit" praktisch immer aufgehoben werden:

> er hat für seine Entscheidung gut**e** Gr**ü**nd**e**.

Das nennt sich dann Nullartikel und wird als Pluralform des indefiniten Artikels angesehen. Aber lässt sich "*guter Grund*" im Nominativ ohne Artikel tatsächlich konstruieren? Für den artikellosen Genitiv Singular "*gut**en** Grund**es***" finde ich tatsächlich einen Beleg:

> "nach der unzweifelhaft eingetretenen Zersetzung einst vorhanderer [= vonhandener] spielerischer Stärke und einer Zementierung dieser 'erreichten' Schwäche darf man guten Grundes demoralisiert und auch schockiert sein." [1](https://www.glubbforum.de/forum/thread/21181-19-spieltag-fsv-mainz-1-fc-n%C3%BCrnberg-vor-dem-spiel/?pageNo=9)

Gemeint ist: "*mit/aus gutem Grund*", hier als adverbialer Genitiv - für meinen Geschmack etwas hochgestochen, aber bildbar und immerhin verständlich. Für den Dativ hast du selbst

> aus gut**em** Grund

gefunden. Da stellt sich wiederum die Frage, ob die Präposition "*aus*" nicht notwendiger Bestandteil der gesamten Nominalgruppe ist, ohne die so ein artikelloser Dativ Singular nicht vorkommen kann.

Dann gibt es noch Fälle wie

> welch gut**er** Grund / welch**er** gut**e** Grund,

soweit "*welch(er)*" als Artikelwort eingeordnet wird, wozu es "einigen Grund" ; ) gibt.

Insgesamt denke ich, die Aufgabestellung ist komplex und sollte klarer eingegrenzt werden. Insbesondere das Problem der sogenannten "Zählbarkeit" sollte zumindest gesehen werden, und man sollte nur solche Kombinationen ermitteln, die auch in realem Sprachgebrauch vorkommen können.

---

Comment: Auch zählbare Nomen können in bestimmten Kontexten ohne Artikel stehen: *Was aber gilt als guter Grund?*

Comment: Ich gebe gutem Grund den Vorzug gegenüber bloßer Mutmaßung, ob ein artikelloser Dativ Singular vorkommen kann.

Comment: @David Vogt: Schönes Beispiel. Wird das verstanden als "ein guter Grund", also gezählt?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: Super Beispiel, etwas abgedreht vom Sprachlevel her, dafür mit umso besser treffender Pointe. Auch hier die Frage: Ist "einem guten Grund" gemeint, also ein "zählbarer" Grund in der Einzahl? Jedenfalls fasse ich das spontan so auf.

Comment: Die Frage ist, ob man zwischen *guter Grund* und *ein guter Grund* noch irgendwie unterscheiden muß (so wie bei *er ist (ein) Polizist*). Aber Konversion in ein Massennomen würde ich ausschließen.